# To select matching strings in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**TableA**

```
Id  | M  | D  |   Y   |
=======================
1  | 10  | 28  | 2012 |
2  | 11  | 29  | 2012 |
3  | 12  | 30  | 2012 |
```

**TableB**

```
Id  | M  | D  |   Y   |
=======================
4  | 09  | 28  | 2012 |
5  | 11  | 29  | 2012 |
6  | 01  | 30  | 2013 |
```

I will search by **M** and **D**

Ex: If matching M = 11 AND D = 29 ... so will return ID(s) **2** , **5**

I can only find by one table like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE M='11' AND Y='29' ORDER BY D ASC , Id DESC;";)
```

But how to find in multiple tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You better use `UNION ALL` (in case `tableB` has identical records) to get all the records. Otherwise just `UNION` will do.

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE M='11' AND Y='29'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE M='11' AND Y='29'
ORDER BY D ASC , Id DESC;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `UNION` clause between two `SELECT`s

```
(SELECT Id, M, D, Y FROM TableA WHERE M='11' AND Y='29')
UNION
(SELECT Id, M, D, Y FROM TableB WHERE M='11' AND Y='29')
ORDER BY D ASC , Id DESC
```

Comment: Parentheses are needed so that the `ORDER` works on the end result not only to the second query.

Comment: This ordering works on sql server 2008 onwards. Not sure on 2005.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE M='11' AND Y='29'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE M='11' AND Y='29'
ORDER BY D ASC , Id DESC;
```